# Bootstrap carousel control not working in DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a news feed application using RSS feed using DOM manipulation.
So here's the structure collapsible accordion -> Carousel (inner and controls) -> Cards(Carousel inner)
I have created cards and inspected them the cards are in dom but my carousel control does not slide.

here's the accordion and carousel rendering function.

```js
const renderAccordionSection = (index, id, title) => {
  let divAccordion = `<div class="accordion-item">
                        <button class="accordion-button ${index === 0 ? "" : "collapsed"}" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse-${id}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-${id}">
                          ${title}
                        </button>
                        <div id="collapse-${id}" class="accordion-collapse collapse ${index === 0 ? "show": ""}" aria-labelledby="heading-${id}" data-bs-parent="#accordionSection">
                          <div class="accordion-body">
                            <div id="indicator-${id}" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel"> 
                              <div class="carousel-inner" id="carousel-inner-${id}">
                              </div>
                              <div>
                              <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#indicator-${id}" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                              <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#indicator-${id}" role="button" data-slide="next">
                              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>`;
  return divAccordion;
}
```

and also my card rendering function which selects the carousel inner id

```js
const renderCarouselItems = (id, items) => {
  const carouselInnerId = document.querySelector(`#carousel-inner-${id}`);

  items.forEach((el, j) => {
    let carouselTemplate = carouselItemTemplate(el, j);
    carouselInnerId.innerHTML += carouselTemplate;
  })

}
```

So why my carousel not working?

Comment: [From the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#usage): "*The data-bs-ride="carousel" attribute is used to mark a carousel as animating starting at page load.*"  That sentence hightlights 2 problems in your code 1) You have `data-ride="carousel"`, not `data-bs-ride` (you also have a few other `data` attributes which seem to be missing the `-bs` part); and 2) Your carousel would only be initialised automatically by Bootstrap if it exists at page load.  You are dynamically adding elements later, but not initialising them.

Comment: You'll need to [init your carousel manually](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#via-javascript) at some point, though if you are repeatedly inserting new slides it might be more complicated, maybe you have to destroy it and re-init it each time?

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is because you are dynamically adding the Html to your document after the initial render bootstrap has not assigned all the appropriate event handlers.

Bootstrap normally does this, at the end of the page load process, when the bootstrap script file runs. It finds all of your carousels and adds the appropriate events.

What you will need to do is manually call the bootstrap initialization script at the very end of all of your Html updates, i.e. each time you do an Html DOM update.

I think the function to call is, this one:

$('#your-carousel-id').carousel();

```js
const renderCarouselItems = (id, items) => {
  const carouselInnerId = document.querySelector(`#carousel-inner-${id}`);

  items.forEach((el, j) => {
    let carouselTemplate = carouselItemTemplate(el, j);
    carouselInnerId.innerHTML += carouselTemplate;
  })
  
  //something like this
  $('#'+id).carousel();

}
```

I found this link while briefly looking up the correct function to call https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp